# Driving a bash program (for a git precommit hook) off a list of rules

Tags: git, bash

I'm writing a git precommit hook, which I believe is executed by bash. I need to check the modified files, and if the content matches a pattern, display an error message.

```
[{
    fileName: "*.html",
    pattern: "\<font\>",
    message: "Don't use font. Use style sheet istead!"
}, 
{
    fileName: "/Admin/*",
    pattern: "string\.Format\(",
    message: "Don't use string.format. Use string interpolation istead!"
},
....
]
```

I have many these kind of rules. How do I define these rules in bash? If bash isn't good at this, how do I implement the precommit hook?

Comment: You simply can't. First pattern can't be parsed without using special XML tools. Besides that it's not guaranteed that shell would be *bash*. You need to be as much generic as possible.

Comment: @0andriy I'm not going to publish it as a product. I just use it in my own working evnironemnt that if I don't have bash I can install one. Besides, why do you mention XML? I'm fine with storing the data in any format.

Comment: @0andriy, ...maybe you mean JSON tools? `jq` is a fine tool for doing that in shell. And `[[ $string = $pattern ]]` will check whether a given string (such as a filename) matches a pattern (such as `*.html`).

Comment: That said, while this *could* be JSON-driven, I don't see any reason not to go the code-as-configuration route @torek suggests.

Comment: Since the *<font>* might be not a tag, or *<* might be written as hex code or via & expression. When I see bash or shell tag on questions like this my eyes are bleeding.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, see above, I meant exactly what I wrote.

Answer (score 2):

On the Git side: hooks may be written in any language, as long as your OS can run the hook via an `exec` style system call.  In general, scripts are run by some shell, often `/bin/sh` which is often *not* bash, but on Unix-like systems, if the first line of the script reads `#! /bin/bash` or `#! /usr/bin/env bash`, for instance, the script will definitely be run with bash.  You can use `#! /usr/bin/env python` to run the script with Python, and so on, as well.

(Also on the Git side, in a pre-commit hook you can use `git diff --cached --name-status` to get a list of files in the proposed commit that differ from those in the `HEAD` commit, including precisely how they differ.  Add an explicit `--find-renames` or `--no-renames` to definitely enable or disable rename detection, regardless of user configuration settings; or use `git diff-index` instead of `git diff`—the rest of the options are the same—to *ignore* user-specified configuration items.)

On the shell script side, bash has many facilities for this, but the simplest is probably just to run the file names through code with explicit glob-style pattern matching and actions:

```
gripe() {
    echo "$@" 1>&2
    GRIPES=$((GRIPES + 1))
}

check_file() {
    case "$1" in
    *.html) if fgrep "<font>" "$2"; then
        gripe "Don't use font. Use style sheet instead!"; fi;;
    */Admin/*) if grep "string\.Format(" "$2"; then gripe ...; fi;;
    esac
}
```

Now we get to the most peculiar part of the whole operation: the form of the file that is to be committed exists *in the index, and not necessarily in the work-tree.*  This is why the code in check_file() above takes two parameters.  One is the name of the file as it will appear in the commit; the other is the name of a *temporary file*, where we will extract the index contents to this file, before inspecting it.

If you're willing to assume that no one ever stages anything that does not already appear in the work-tree, you can skip a lot of this complexity.  Using `--name-only` and `--diff-filter`, we can get a list of file names for files that are `A`dded or `M`odified and look at their work-tree versions:

```
GRIPES=0
git diff-index --cached --diff-filter=AM HEAD |
    while read path; do
        check_file "$path" "$path"
    done
```

To do a proper job, we need to extract each file into a temporary file (perhaps using `git checkout-index --temp`, for instance) and scan the temporary file, then remove the temporary.

When we are all done the shell variable $GRIPES counts the number of complaints made, which could be used to prevent the commit.

Comment: *fgrep* for XML?! Nice try!

Comment: @0andriy: we're not looking for actual XML—or even HTML—just for the literal string `<font>`, hence fgrep. The OP does not seem to care to do a perfect job, just to detect some particularly common errors.